# How can I post a suggestion or bug for Disks

Tags: udisks, gnome-disk-utility

Disks > About identifies this software as gnome-disk-utility and UDisks.  Alt-F2 "ubuntu-bug gnome-disk-utility" results in a dead end because the system claims that it is not an Ubuntu package and that third party packages should be removed.  Alt-F2 "ubuntu-bug UDisks" also is a dead end.  How can I post a suggestion or a bug about Disks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome Disks Utility development and bug tracking occurs at  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility

Keep in mind that it's their working space, not a public space:

- When folks show up with an understanding of how Gnome works and have a positive and patient attitude, the Gnome developers respond warmly and generously.
- When folks show up behaving boorishly --impatient, ignorant of Gnome design or goals, demanding, opinionated-- they get fire breathed right back at them, then ignored completely.